# Getting 404 error when reload page in react+wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building a WordPress plugin using react and I'm using react on the WordPress frontend. When I change route using react and reload the page then I'm getting the 404 error

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const defaultConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

const ReactJs = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        'index': './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
}

module.exports = [ReactJs];
```

I want the solution within my plugin directory. Not in the .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own. Here is the solution.
I load react on a page whose slug is `frontend-dashboard`. So I add a basename in **BrowserRouter**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter basename='/frontend-dashboard/'>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("frontend-dashboard")
);
```

And after that, I create a custom endpoint for my WordPress plugin.

```
add_action( 'init', 'tf_add_rewrite_endpoint' );
function tf_add_rewrite_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'hotels', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'add-new-hotel', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
```

Once I registered the new endpoint, I checked the newly registered endpoint in the current URL. If it matched, I am setting the template path to frontend-dashboard.php where actually react loaded by this id `frontend-dashboard`

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'tf_template_include' );
function tf_template_include( $template ) {
    $page_slug = array('hotels', 'add-new-hotel');
    if ( is_page() && in_array( get_query_var( 'pagename' ), $page_slug ) ) {
        $template = TF_TEMPLATE_PATH . 'page-templates/frontend-dashboard.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```